# Admin view only navigate bar PHP

Tags: php

I'm planning to create a header navigate bar for both user & admin with different content. If it is the user, so they will only see the Log out button. If it is the Admin, they will see button "Usermanagement" and "Logout" using php. For now I didn't to manage to ensure that the php read the status of current user. 'roles' = 'Y' is consider as admin, i store it inside mssql. Below is my code.

```
<?php if( isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))
        { ?>
        <a class="right" href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
          <?php if( isset($_SESSION['roles']) && $_SESSION['roles']===['Y']) ?>
            <a class="right" href="userManagement.php">User Profile</a>
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <a class="right" href="login.php">Login</a>
        <a class="right" href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php } ?>
```

any help would highly appreciated, i've been searching and applying many code since last 4 days, none of the code working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want this or not.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
    <a class="right" href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
    <?php if ($_SESSION['roles'] === "Y") {  ?>
        <a class="right" href="userManagement.php">User Profile</a>
    <?php }  ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a class="right" href="login.php">Login</a>
    <a class="right" href="register.php">Register</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi. seems like not working. user profile button not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally output HTML code you need to echo it from PHP.  Here's what I think you want.  I have kept your formatting

```
<?php
if( isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))
  {echo '<a class="right" href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';}
if( isset($_SESSION['roles']) && $_SESSION['roles']===['Y'])
  {echo '<a class="right" href="userManagement.php">User Profile</a>';}
else
  {echo '<a class="right" href="login.php">Login</a>';
   echo '<a class="right" href="register.php">Register</a>';}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, this command displayed all button except User profile button... not sure why, the php seems doesn't read the roles = Y

Comment: I didn't change the logic of your code.  I showed you how to output it.  Surely you are able to shift stuff around to do what you want.  If that button was not displayed then the conditions for that if are not correct.